# Bootstrap messing with Wordpress CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please help every time I add bootstrap css link to my page to display a certain layout my navigation bar disappears in WordPress.

Comment: Do you have a url or code sample to check? you should add the boostrap css before your wordpress theme style.

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

CSS libraries will override each other given certain rules of precedence. I would suggest adding some of the code for the navigation bar and we can see more details of what is going on. We need more info to figure out what is going on. Most likely, if you add the correct bootstrap classes to the tags in your navigation bar, this will fix the problem.